# Biostar N3150NH driver

Tags: drivers

I want to build a PC based on a Biostar N3150NH mainboard. Unfortunately on the Biostar page no Linux drivers are listed. If they don't have drivers is it possible to use the mainboard with Ubuntu anyway?

Has someone already managed to run a Mini ITX board working with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a number of BioStar motherboards with Linux installed on them and never experienced any problems.  Also, I very rarely use proprietary drivers from motherboard manufactures on Ubuntu.

I have on rare occasions had motherboards that were shipped defective and received either a refund or replacement.

Checking the [Biostar N3150NH specs](http://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=804#specification) it is using the `Intel HD Graphics`, of which Ubuntu Supports.  I have the same Graphics in my Gigabyte Brix and don't experience any problems.  I also used the `Additional Drivers` update to check for optimization.  I didn't notice any difference between the default installed drivers and the alternate proprietary drivers.  I wasn't experiencing any problems, I just checked out of curiosity for testing.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I will give it a shoot.